# Get tab-delimited variables from each line in txt

Tags: java, string, file

Can u help me with splitting tab-delinited words from each line in text file.

For example file contains this data:

```
26317273105      77016080517    2015-02-11 04:33:37      2015-02-11 04:33:39    2015-02-11 04:39:00 
26317273123      77715354350    2015-02-11 04:33:37      2015-02-11 04:33:39    2015-02-11 04:33:00  
26317273125      77715354350    2015-02-11 04:33:37      2015-02-11 04:33:42    2015-02-11 04:33:00  
26317273127      77715354350    2015-02-11 04:33:37      2015-02-11 04:33:43    2015-02-11 04:33:00
```

I need to get this values into differnt variables. For example, number=26317273105, phone=77016080517, date1=2015-02-11 04:33:37 etc.

Plz help.

Edit: This is what i try:

```
public static void GetLines() {

    try {
    File fileDir = new File("c:\\download\\tmpfile.txt");

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
       new InputStreamReader(
                  new FileInputStream(fileDir), "windows-1251"));

    String str;

    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] array = str.split("\t");
                System.out.println(array[0]);
                System.out.println(array[1]);
                System.out.println(array[2]);
                System.out.println(array[3]);
                System.out.println(array[4]);
    }

            in.close();
    } 
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

But in output i have values only from first line.

```
26317273105 
77016080517 
2015-02-11 04:33:37 
2015-02-11 04:33:39
2015-02-11 04:39:00
```

Comment: Please edit your post and add some sourcecode you tried so far.

Comment: @SebastianStigler added what i tryed.But i have in output values only from 1st line

Answer (score 0):

lets say you have a String that is tab delimited like this:

```
String a = "String1\tString2";
```

you can split it into an array of strings using the following:

```
String[] array = a.split("\t");     // "\t" denotes a tab
```

and assign it to a variable by going through the array:

```
String foo = array[0]   // 0 is the first element in the array
String bar = array[1]   // ....and so on
```

`foo` will contain `String1` and `bar` will contain `String2`.

Hope this helps

Comment: thx. I tryed this. But i have in output values only from 1st line.

Answer (score 0):

The following will split data read in from input into separate words

```
Pattern wordPattern = Pattern.compile("\\S+");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);
while(scanner.hasNext(wordPattern)) {
    System.out.println("== " + scanner.next(wordPattern));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works.

```
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        String sCurrentLine;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\data.txt"));
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] str = sCurrentLine.split("\\t");
            String s1 = str[0];
            String s2 = str[1];
            String s3 = str[2];
            String s4 = str[3];
            String s5 = str[4];
            System.out.println("s1 = "+s1+"\ns2 = "+s2+"\ns3 = "+s3+"\ns4 = "+s4+"\ns5 = "+s5);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Output is:

```
s1 = 26317273105
s2 = 77016080517
s3 = 2015-02-11 04:33:37
s4 = 2015-02-11 04:33:39
s5 = 2015-02-11 04:39:00 
s1 = 26317273123
s2 = 77715354350
s3 = 2015-02-11 04:33:37
s4 = 2015-02-11 04:33:39
s5 = 2015-02-11 04:33:00  
s1 = 26317273125
s2 = 77715354350
s3 = 2015-02-11 04:33:37
s4 = 2015-02-11 04:33:42
s5 = 2015-02-11 04:33:00  
s1 = 26317273127
s2 = 77715354350
s3 = 2015-02-11 04:33:37
s4 = 2015-02-11 04:33:43
s5 = 2015-02-11 04:33:00
```